# How to make image view scroll together with grid view in scroll view

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, scrollview, android-scrollview

I have some image view and text view above a grid view which is use to display reviews/comments of customers. And the image view is for product illustration and text view is description of the product.
When i am scrolling the grid view, only the grid view part is scrolled. How can i make the images and text also scroll up.
[click here to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxKho.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/choseitem_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:id="@+id/choseitem_title"
        />
 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:id="@+id/choseitem_price"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:id="@+id/score"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            />

 </LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:text="Comment"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/comment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NestedScrollView wrap all of your view to make it scrolled.

```
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!--        put your content layout here-->
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

And your layout should look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/choseitem_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/choseitem_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/choseitem_price"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/score"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Comment"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/comment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </GridView>

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep as Nguyen mentioned, wrapping your entire XML code within nested scroll view will work, he even generously helped to provide you the final code.

That said, I'd like to try and elaborate on why this works.
Currently your GridView is scrolling mainly because it is a property of the GridView layout. As seen from the documentation
"A view that shows items in **two-dimensional scrolling grid**. The items in the grid come from the ListAdapter associated with this view."
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView

To make any other component scrollable, you would need a ScrollView, which would enable that View to scroll vertically, you may choose to add HorizontalScrollView , should you want to have a horizontally scrolling view.

But for your particular use-case you would need to add a NestedScrollView instead, as you have multiple views, rather than just one child view. As defined "NestedScrollView is just like ScrollView, but it supports acting as both a nested scrolling parent and child on both new and old versions of Android. Nested scrolling is enabled by default."

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/widget/NestedScrollView

Hope that this helps you better answer the solution, rather than just using the answer given!